# How to estimate transform matrix between two similar images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, geometry, affinetransform, homography

I want to estimate transformation matrix between two images, which are taken at the same scene from different positions.

I tried two methods:

First method related links:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html
https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d2c/tutorial_real_time_pose.html

I use extraction of keypoints, descriptions, and image match to find corresponding points between two images, then use findHomography to compute the matrix. However, these image match method doesn't work well although I used various techniques mentioned in the above links.

Second method, I tried esimateRigidTransform. However, it returns empty matrix for following two example images.
[image]
[image]

In the doc of the function, "Two raster images. In this case, the function first finds some features in the src image and finds the corresponding features in dst image. After that, the problem is reduced to the first case." It seems it uses similar ideas as the first method.

My questions:
1. Why esimateRigidTransform returns empty matrix for such similar images?
2. Are there better method for computing transform matrix between similar images which are taken at the same scene from different positions? For example, can I skip the feature detection and match steps？

Thanks.

Comment: the feature extraction and matching steps in estimateRigidTransformation are probably not so good and deprecated. Typical approach is to use keypount matching like sift or surf or orb features. Your image has some significant change in perspective and your planar objects don't have much texture to describe, which might be some of the problems distracting the keypoint matching. Perspective homographies are only correct for planar scenes or pure rotational camera change of a pinhole camera.

Comment: I completely agree with @Micka, you might want to look at pre-processing the images before performing keypoint matching (like unsharp mask). Also, fine tuning the detector parameters might also help!

Comment: Thanks. So the first method is the solution. However, it seems that it is very hard to apply the first method in real open scenes.

Comment: I wonder if by genetics algorithm you could train a CNN to manipulate the image with geometrics transformations, to achieve a best fitting solution.That makes sense?